# Cannot read property 'companyWebsite' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

if(companyDetailData.companyWebsite!== "" && companyDetailData.companyWebsite!== undefined && companyDetailData.companyWebsite!== null){
^
var isWebsite = true;
}

Comment: please provide more information. using formating can help others so see your code more readable and you may find your answer faster

Answer (score 0):

First make checks on `companyDetailData` then check `companyDetailData.companyWebsite`.

**Like this**

```js
if (!!companyDetailData && companyDetailData.companyWebsite) {
  var isWebsite = true;
}
```